# Button disappears after animating it

Tags: ios, swift, animation, button

I'm using UIView Extension for button to slide it up with keyboard.

```
extension UIView {
func bindToKeyboard() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillChange(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    let duration = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    let curve = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
    let startingFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let endingFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let deltaY = endingFrame.origin.y - startingFrame.origin.y

    let options = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve << 16)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: options, animations: {
        self.frame.origin.y += deltaY
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Then in ViewController just using :

```
func setUpView() {
        okayButton.bindToKeyboard()
        self.isHeroEnabled = true
    }
```

But the problem is when I press other button on the screen:

[image: Gif]

Save button disappears after tapping on other button, when it is in the "upper position", and appears when it's on the bottom.  What am I doing wrong? How to prevent/fix it?

Edit: There is no action on any of these buttons! (+,-,save)

Thanks!

Comment: problem in key board is not hide.

Comment: There is no actions on any of these buttons.

Comment: Have you tried applying a transform to the view rather than adjusting the frame? I have a feeling it's something to do with with the frame being adjusted and the layout being re-calculated incorrectly.

Comment: Show '+' button action code and storyboard binding snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to update `self.view` . What you can do is create a `IBOutlet` bottom spacing for the save button.

```
@IBOutlet weak var saveButtonBottomSpacing: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

1. When keyboard is open, set bottom spacing constant to keyboard's height.
2. When keyboard is dismissed, restore the bottom spacing. May be 0 or your desired value.

You can make this changes within `UIView` animation block.

Comment: Can I somehow access Constraint in UIView extension ?

Comment: If your save button is inside that view, Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Hide (resign) your keyboard upon successful action on 'Save' button.

Here is sample code you need to update in your Save button action.

```
@IBAction func btnSave(sender: Any){

    // add this line in your upon, successful action on save button
    yourTextView.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: It is not solving problem. I will resign it after tapping on Save button, but the problem is when user click on "+" and he can't save it with keyboard on screen, because there is no save Button.

Comment: Show '+' button code and its storyboard connection snapshot.